# Problem importing matrix in Python from Excel and maybe some problems with if elif statments

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying running this code with some problems to solve. I'm at first trying inserting "BOD" as the name of the output and "6" as the number of input parameters.

```py
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import ExcelWriter
    from numpy import *
    
    OutputName = input('please enter the name of the output (BOD,COD,TSS)');
    InputNum = input('please enter the number of input parameters (6 or 12) = ');
    file_name = 'biowin_withMalfunction.xlsx'
    
    if OutputName == 'BOD':
               Output_num=1
               if InputNum == 6:
                  Data = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Elisa\test_conv_Fatone\biowin_withMalfunction.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='ANN full data for BOD_6Params')
                  print (Data)
               elif InputNum ==12:
                Data = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Elisa\test_conv_Fatone\biowin_withMalfunction.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='ANN full data for BOD')
    elif OutputName == 'COD':
               Output_num=2
               if InputNum == 6:
                Data = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Elisa\test_conv_Fatone\biowin_withMalfunction.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='ANN full data for COD_6ParamsD')
               elif InputNum ==12:
                Data = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Elisa\test_conv_Fatone\biowin_withMalfunction.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='ANN full data for COD')
    else:
               Output_num=3
               if InputNum == 6:
                Data = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Elisa\test_conv_Fatone\biowin_withMalfunction.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='ANN full data for TSS_6Params')
               elif InputNum ==12:
                Data = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name="ANN full data for TSS")
    
    index = Output_num -3;
    X = Data[0:end-2,0:end]
```

the error is:

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Elisa\test_conv\ANN_Converted.py", line 42, in <module>
        X = Data[0:end-2,0:end]
    NameError: name 'Data' is not defined
```

It seems that the variable Data is not created with pd.reading, in fact, if I try print(Data) it does not exist. Can anybody help me finding the problem/problems?
Can I share the input excel file? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about your conditions.  What happens if every individual test is `False`?  What happens if *all* your tests are `False` ?

There is a path through your decision tree in which *no file is opened*.  This is currently obtaining, so `Data` doesn't exist, as you determined.

In this case the problem is likely that `input()` returns a *string*, whereas you are testing for an *integer*.

Thus either test for strings:

```py
if inputNum == "5"
```

or cast inputNum to an int:

```py
inputNum = int(inputNum)
```

*before* you do any testing.

Comment: yes exactly. But if I insert BOD as OutputName and then 6 as InputNum, the first conditions are satified so they are TRUE. The code should read the excel and print Data. Is not rigth? @2e0byo

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: ok.... so how can I fix it properly?

Comment: test for a string ("5" not 5), or cast to an int (`inputNum = int(inputNUm)`).  And in general get used to using `type(thing)` to check for this kind of stuff---it can help a lot